# General logging with ELMAH

Tags: logging, elmah

Is ELMAH a good tool for general logging (Read: Audit logging)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only designed for reporting unhandled exceptions, its not a logging framework.
You should use something else for general logging.